# How do I separate my models out in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, split

I'm trying to learn python/django.

Right now, I have all of my models in models.py

Is it possible to have my models broken out so that I can have a single file per model in a separate models folder so that I can do something like:

> ~/myproject/myapp/models/user.py
>   ~/myproject/myapp/models/group.py

Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is possible, just make sure to import all the models you create in `__init__.py` in your `models` directory. In your case, it would look like this:

```
# __init__.py
from .user import UserModel
from .group import GroupModel
```

This needs to be done because Django looks in `app.models` for an app's models.

As others have mentioned, for versions of Django prior to 1.7, you'll also need to specify your app's name in the `app_label` attribute in the `Meta` class in your model:

```
class UserModel(models.model):
    # fields here

    class Meta:
        app_label = "myapp"
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#app-label

Comment: This drove me crazy, so for those who come after, in 1.10 there needs to be a '.': `from .user import UserModel`. As mentioned here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package

Comment: also care take care of the order of the `import` s in `__init__.py`. else you will get strange error like `First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'`

Answer (score 5):

You could have a folder called `models` but then in each model class you'll need to include:

```
class Meta:
    app_label="appname goes here"
```

*ps. Don't forget a `__ init__.py` file like I always do.*

Comment: Can't we use some inheritance? define some base_model.py with the class Meta and then this should do for all the derivatives of that class?

Comment: @HamzaOuaghad a bit late, but yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

in the models folder you create the file `__init__.py` you import your class in it.
ex : `myproject/myapp/models/__init__.py`
`from .myfile import myclass`