# Django 1.7 Not Finding New Model w/ makemigrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a project with several apps and many data models.  I'm using Django 1.7 and Python 2.7.

I've organized the models into app-level modules.

```
- common/
  -- models/
    --- __init__.py
    --- these_models.py
    --- those_models.py
```

I've added a new file in this structure and Django's `makemigration` command is not detecting changes.

If I put the new models in an existing model file the migration files are created perfectly, everything migrates and runs great.  Once I put them into a new file Django doesn't find them.  They aren't in a new app - it's an existing `app/models/` module, just a new file.  I don't `import *` (ewwww) in the `__init__.py` or anything.

In Django 1.4 I had to use the `Meta`'s `app_label` but don't do this anymore.

Any thoughts?  Will I need to make the migration files manually (I have no problem doing this)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534206/how-do-i-separate-my-models-out-in-django

Comment: This is not relevant to my question as I'm using Django 1.7.  Also, I mentioned in my question that is not relevant.  Did you read my question?

Comment: You should import your models in the `__init__.py` inside `models`. No one is telling you to use `*`.

Comment: @snahor This does not follow our current project paradigm.  Django can handle what I'm describing and I'm not sure why it's not this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django does now support models in subfolders without needing to specify the `Meta class` and `app_label` but it's still python and doesn't magically load all modules in the `models` folder.

You still need to import your models into your `app/models/__init__.py`.

Comment: This is not true.  My project has about 8 model modules with about 2 dozen model files across the modules.  Not one is imported in the `app/models/__init__.py`.  We just reference all our models as `from app.models.these_models import SomeModel`.  Django seems to handle this paradigm just fine.  (other than this use case)

Comment: @Rico in that case you are "getting lucky" by the fact there are imports for those models. If there is a period of time a model in one of those files is not imported by a module auto-imported by django, `makemigrations` would fail to see the models and delete it. Sounds a little dangerous! This is also the problem with why your new models aren't picked up by makemigrations. Nothing is importing them. This is a dependency nobody would expect (removing an import should not cause massive changes in the way the app works) and I recommend importing in `__init__.py` where django expects to find them