# using a foreign key "related name" string when your models.py file is actually a dir

Tags: python, django

I understand that if I want to establish a foreign key relationship for this model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass
```

... from this location

```
/myproject
    /myapp
       models.py (MyModel)
```

... I can use a "string-named" relationship to avoid import-time errors.

```
# this is in a different app within myproject

class DependentModel(models.Model):
    my_model = models.ForeignKey('mayapp.MyModel')
```

But how do I establish that *same* ForeignKey relationship *with a string* when my models have been distributed across a models dir (e.g. not contained within one models.py file)

```
/myproject
    /myapp
       /models
           /one.py (MyModel)
           /two.py (other models)
```

(Assume that I can't just import the model directly, ala `from myapp.models.one import MyModel`)

Comment: Have you tried something and got any error?

Comment: Like @Gocht said, did you try `'myapp.models.MyModel'`. The worst that happens is you get an error which you can add to your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Aha! I should have taken just a couple more minutes to search; this is possible simply by importing your models from within the `__init__.py` file inside the models dir:

```
# myproject/myapp/models/__init__.py

from one import MyModel
```

Related question: [How do I separate my models out in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534206/how-do-i-separate-my-models-out-in-django)