# Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django, pydot, django-extensions

I am using django-extensions for graph-model representation. 
When running this command:

```
 $ ./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my.png
```

Error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label braces is missing a models.py module.

My Project structure:

```
Project
        app1
            models
                 abc.py
                 xyz.py
                 __init__.py
             urls.py
             admin.py
             views.py
             __init__.py
       app2
            models
                 abc1.py
                 xyz1.py
                 __init__.py
             urls.py
             admin.py
             views.py
             __init__.py
```

My models/abc.py:

```
class Abc(AbstractBaseUser):

MALE = "M"
FEMALE = "F"

SEX_CHOICES = [
    (MALE, "Male"),
    (FEMALE, "Female"),
]

SEX_CHOICES_AND_BLANK = [('', 'Select Gender')] + SEX_CHOICES


email = models.EmailField(_('Email Address'), max_length=70, unique=True)
first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name'), max_length=30)
last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name'), max_length=30)
username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=70, unique=True)
gender = models.CharField(_("Gender"), max_length=1, choices=SEX_CHOICES, blank=True)
contact_number = models.CharField(
    _("Contact Number"),
    max_length=15,
    blank=True,
    validators=[
        RegexValidator(r'^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$')
    ])

# Profile extras
image = ImageFileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True, default='user-default.png')
about = models.TextField(_("about me"), blank=True)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Where is `braces` coming from? Using names like `app1` and `app2` instead of your actual code makes it more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported all your models in models' **init**.py? It is required to import all the models in models' **init**.py like given in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534206/how-do-i-separate-my-models-out-in-django?answertab=votes#tab-top). If it is not imported, *django-extensions* won't be able to get all the models.

Comment: Yeah.. I have imported all models in models'init.py file.

Comment: I have resolved this problem, But I am getting empty file when running this command

Comment: Can you please update the question with the solution?