# Django "Model class <Class> doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS" after splitting models

Tags: python, django

I'm getting this error and I've been trying to fix it for many hours, it came up once I separated my models.py into a directory with multiple files.

This is the current structure of my project. I have omitted many files, but these are the relevant ones:

- Project_folder

  - academy

    - app1
    - app2

      - manage.py
      - models

        - _ _ init _ _.py
        - content.py
        - session.py
    - app3
  - config
  - static

Before, I had all my models in a single file inside app2, called models.py. However, as the file started to grow too large, I separated each of the models into different categories. Also, in `__init__.py` I imported these elements:

```
from academy.app2.models.content import *
from academy.app2.models.session import *
```

Now, when I try to make migrations with `python manage.py makemigrations app2`, as usual, I'm getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class app2.models.content.Reward doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

When I searched for this error, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534206/how-do-i-separate-my-models-out-in-django), however, when I add the Meta Class declarating the app_label, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'reward' models in application 'app2': <class 'academy.app2.models.content.Reward'> and <class 'app2.models.content.Reward'>.
```

This is my Config file for app2:

```
class App2Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'academy.app2'
```

This is my INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'academy.app2.apps.App2Config',
    ...
]
```

This error did not occur when I had a single models.py file, but when I separated it into separate files. I also tried to create an additional base model, and define in that model the Meta Class, inheriting in the rest of the models, without success.

Comment: Does changing the `CoreConfig` to `App2Config` in `INSTALLED_APPS` work? The actual location of your `AppConfig` class.

Comment: @Abhyudai I'm sorry. It was a typo. It's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

After many attempts, I found the solution to my problem:

First, I edited `__init.py__` to the following syntax:

```
from .content import *
from .session import *
from .system import *
```

In addition, I updated the imports from one file to another, from the `app2.models.file` format to this: `academy.app2.models.file`.

It was not necessary to add a base class. I was now able to run the migrations correctly. I hope this is helpful to someone.