# Dask task serialization in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dask, prefect

I am trying to set up prefect 2 with dask to run some tasks in django. One simple example with not much code runs fine but a larger example fails with:

```
distributed.worker - ERROR - Could not deserialize task ****-****-****-****
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2185, in execute
    function, args, kwargs = await self._maybe_deserialize_task(ts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2158, in _maybe_deserialize_task
    function, args, kwargs = _deserialize(*ts.run_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2835, in _deserialize
    kwargs = pickle.loads(kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 73, in loads
    return pickle.loads(x)
  File "/tmp/tmpb11md_6wprefect/my_project/models/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from my_project.models.my_model import *
  File "/tmp/tmpb11md_6wprefect/my_project/models/api_key.py", line 14, in <module>
    class ApiKey(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

The problem here is that I use an [**init**.py in a model directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5534251/1100089) instead of using multiple apps etc. To circumvent this error in other places I did set up the django environment at the beginning of each task, e.g.:

```
import datetime
import xyz
import django

os.environ.setdefault(
    "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
    os.environ.get("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "core.settings"),
)

django.setup()

# No we import the models

from my_project.models import MyModel
```

This worked fine so far. But the deserialization in dask does not seem to work this way. It seems it tries to import the model directory before running any code in the serialized task.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to help with the Prefect question, but I won't be able to help much with the Django issue.

One solution you may try is creating a flow run from deployment via an API call instead of running your flow directly in your Django application. This way, the flow would run in a separate process, not interfering with your Django app. [This Prefect Discourse topic](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-create-a-flow-run-from-deployment-orchestrator-pattern/803) shows how you could set this up.

Even easier might be to do it with Python `requests` rather than the Prefect client - this way, your Django app doesn't even need to have Prefect installed in your environment. I think [this might be the best solution here](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/how-to-trigger-a-flow-run-from-a-deployment-via-api-call-using-python-requests-library-or-from-a-terminal-using-curl/1396).

Comment: The problem here is Django, not Prefect. I use some Django Models in the Prefect Tasks so I would like to keep them in the flow.